# Log4js-node can't find cluster module

Tags: reactjs, logging

I have installed [logjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js) without any error but it shows this when I try to access it:

```
 ./node_modules/log4js/lib/clustering.js
 [1] Module not found: Can't resolve 'cluster' in 
 '/usr/share/client/node_modules/log4js/lib'
 [1] Compiling...
 [1] Failed to compile.
```

My npm version is 5.6.0.